# Saving configuration in shipping method in backend goes to frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

When saving in backend (shipping method configuration) my site goes to frontend without saving.

Comment: Sounds like there is some error during save, or a 3rd party module is issuing a bad redirect. Start with checking your logs. Including web service error log. If nothing reveals itself,  disable all 3rdparty shipping modules.

Comment: Disabled all 3rd party modules but the problem is still here.

Comment: Same as me. Certain sections in configuration backend redirects me to the frontend base URL after hitting "Save config", without saving anything. It seems a problem of redirection. I checked the URL rewrites section, but there are no records concerning the admin URLs.

Comment: I tested my site on local with mamp and is working fine. I think it's the hosting doing something wrong on my space. In my case the hosting is NETSONS.

Comment: Exactly the same! In my local environment everything is working fine. On production space, hosted by Netsons, this error occurs. 
Some sections of configuration save parameters, others, like shipping or payment methods, redirect to the frontend page..

Comment: Sound like you should team up and lodge an ossue with your provider.

Comment: Also Magento Connect doesn't work, when I try to install the page breaks.  I've Netsons Hosting Business plan.

Comment: The problem occurs on all my websites hosted by netsons after some weeks even the site has not been touched

Comment: We found a solution: you must contact via ticket Netsons and ask a ModSecurity Exception.